# Use VSCode Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to use VSCode Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard,

on "Apply the following keyboard mapping scheme:" menu,

select "Visual Studio Code" and save.

> Restart Visual Studio 2019 to take effect

Comment: Restart Visual Studio 2019 to take effect